# Why do I have to reload the page in order to get my single page application to recognize external javascript files?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, components, angular-router

I have a single page application built with angular 7. When I navigate to certain pages I notice that some parts of the DOM are improperly structured. However, when I refresh the page the DOM is able to restructure the HTML the way that it was intended. My single page application uses external javascript and css files from a template, which have been added to my angular.json file. However, when I navigate away from certain pages, using angular-router, then navigate back to the previous page, the HTML is not properly structured. It is only when I refresh the page does it structure the content correctly. My question is: What is causing this and how do I get my single page application to recognize and implement both external css and javascript files using without the refreshing the page?

**I have tried to restart the angular server with ng-serve**

**Here is an example of my home page which uses external javascript file to create a slider for my home page banner**

```
 <div class="eco_wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <app-home-banner></app-home-banner>
    <app-home-eco-services></app-home-eco-services>
    <app-home-eco-promotion></app-home-eco-promotion>
    <app-home-eco-video></app-home-eco-video>
    <app-home-eco-products></app-home-eco-products>
    <app-home-eco-testimonal></app-home-eco-testimonal>
    <app-home-eco-blog></app-home-eco-blog>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**Here is an example of how I added the external css files to my angular.json styles array.**

```
       {
         "input": "src/assets/css/bootstrap.css"
       },
       {
        "input": "src/assets/css/font-awesome.css"
       },
       {
         "input": "src/assets/css/chosen.min.css"
       },
       {
         "input": "src/assets/css/slick-slider.css"
       },
       {
         "input": "src/assets/css/slick-slider.css"
       },
       {
         "input": "src/assets/css/owl.carousel.css"
       },
```

**Here is an example of how I added my external js files to the angular.json scripts array**

```
    "src/assets/js/jquery.js",
    "src/assets/js/bootstrap-lab.js",
    "src/assets/js/bootstrap.js",
    "src/assets/js/slick-slider.js",
    "src/assets/js/jquery.bxslider.js",
    "src/assets/js/owl.carousel.js",
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of error in `console`?

Comment: @randomSoul no errors in the console.

Comment: For UI issues, please provide a [mcve] reproducing it.

Comment: @Maryannah is the code I provided not enough? I not sure what you are asking of me. How can I reproduce the error without rebuilding a single page app?

Comment: @Maryannah I have update the question with more code to help give more insight about the application.

Comment: @meddy https://stackblitz.com